# HTML 5 Application Cache catch events in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, offline-caching

I've created a website using HTML 5 offline Application Cache and it works well in most cases, but for some users it fails. In Chrome, when the application is being cached, the progress is displayed for each file and also error messages if something goes wrong, like:

Application Cache Checking event

Application Cache Downloading event

...

Application Cache Progress event (7 of 521) http://localhost/HTML5App/js/main.js
...

Application Cache Error event: Failed to commit new cache to storage, would exceed quota.

I've added event listeners to window.applicationCache (error, noupdate, obsolete, etc.), but there is no information stored on the nature of the error.

Is there a way to access this information from the web site using JavaScript ?
I would like to determine somehow which file caused the error or what kind of error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the spec doesn't mention that the exact cause of the exception should be included in the error.  Currently the console is your only friend.

To wit, your current error "exceed quota" is due to the fact that Chrome currently limits the storage to 5MB.  You can work around this by creating an app package that requests unlimited_Storage via the permission model.  See http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide.html#live for more details.

If you want specific error messages on the "onerror" handler raise a bug on http://crbug.com/new